# Proving $2^n=2^m=k$ in $2^{2n}+2^m=k^2+k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

While solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685950/when-is-22n22m21-a-perfect-square) on this site I arrived at the equation $$2^{2n}+2^m=k^2+k$$
where $m, n, k$ are natural numbers and $k\ge 2$. How to prove that $2^n=2^m=k$ if $m\le 2n$ ? I have found that $m=2n$ does not hold for the equation but was not able to do more. 
Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Factor it (assuming $2n \gt m$) as $2^m(2^{2n-m}+1)=k(k+1)$  The two factors on each side are relatively prime, so we must have $2^m=k, 2^{2n-m}+1=k+1$ or the other way around.  If $k+1=2^m, k$ cannot be one more than a power of $2$ unless $k=3, m=2$

Comment: Thank you. May I with the help of your solution answer the question I was solving?

Comment: Sure.  The idea of factoring is important in number theory.  If you can show the factors are coprime, you know they have to pair up this way.

Comment: would you please include the proof of the proposition about co-prime numbers you used here.

Comment: There is a mistake your claim is wrong. For e.g $2*15=6*5$ they are co-prime but not equal.